# Trouble with special characters in Vue input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple form in Vue but need the value of an input to contain less than and greater than symbols along with a few pieces of data. This is causing Vue to break on compile since it's not valid. How can I make it work?

Here's an example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="DAT" name="DAT" :value="
  <USERID>item.user_id</USERID>
"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        user_id: "123456"
      }
    }
  },
  template: '<input type="text" id="DAT" name="DAT" :value="`<USERID>${item.user_id}</USERID>`"/>'
}).$mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```